# Setting environment variables accessible to program in root

Tags: python, linux, unix, environment-variables, raspberry-pi

I'm encountering an issue with my program not finding the environment variables when it is run as root.  I currently have the program do:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python3
    from i2clibraries import i2c_adxl345
    #various other imports

    euid=os.geteuid()
    if euid != 0:
        args=['sudo',sys.executable]+sys.argv+[os.environ]
        os.execlpe('sudo',*args)

    #rest of program
```

Along with the environment variables, the necessary files are located in the directory this program is located in /home/pi/project-test

How do I set the environment variables to be accessible to this program when it restarts itself as root?  They are:

```
    export QUICK2WIRE_API_HOME=~/project-test/quick2wire-python-api
    export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$QUICK2WIRE_API_HOME
```

Doing those exports within the directory of my program fixes it when run as user (pi) but not for root. Can I fix the QUICK2WIRE_API_HOME location above or do I need to load all of my libraries and programs into another location?

Note: substituting 'sudo -E' or 'sudo -E su' in does not carry the environment variables set as I expected.  By the way, the actual error received is:

```
    ImportError: No module named quick2wire.i2c
```

which is what the environment variables set the path to. Also, it has to be run as root as some of the program accesses the GPIO's and running as user (pi) returns:

```
    RuntimeError: No access to /dev/mem
```

I've also toyed with the idea of breaking it up using multiprocessing or threading but both are just too far above my head at the moment to understand what I need to include and where to set functions, args, etc.

The complete program can be found [here.](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c2ba98f82d452597c40f)

UPDATE: I redownloaded all the pertinent files into /root via [Thinkbowl](http://think-bowl.com/raspberry-pi/installing-the-think-bowl-i2c-libraries-for-python/).  Still doesn't want to accept the quick2wire library which is located in /root.  Currently /root looks like:

```
    .              .config         .gvfs        quick2wire-python-api
    ..             .dbus           i2clibraries .Xauthority
    .bash_history  .Desktop        .idlerc      .xsession-errors
    .bashrc        .gpio.sh        .local
    .cache         .gstreamer-0.10 .profile
```

with i2c* and .quick* being the two libraries downloaded from thinkbowl. When I perform:

```
    env | grep quick2wire
```

in /root I get:

```
    OLDPWD=/root/quick2wire-python-api
    QUICK2WIRE_API_HOME=/root/quick2wire-python-api
    PYTHON=$PYTHONPATH:$QUICK2WIRE_API_HOME:/root/quick2wire-python-api
```

Comment: Since you are doing this in a linux environment, try copying these commands into your /root/.bashrc file.  This file will update these environment vars

Comment: Ok, well I added these commands into the /root/.bashrc file:

export QUICK2WIRE_API_HOME=~/quick2wire-python-api
export PYTHON=$PYTHONPATH:$QUICK2WIRE_API_HOME

as well as redownloaded the libraries from thinkbowl (including one step I had forgotten) into /root and it's still giving me the error. The post is updated with more information. Thank you so much!

Comment: Do no run as root .. create a user to run as and give it only the permissions it needs. Linux is not designed to have user applications running as root.  This is not a python question but a Linux question.